# Running animations with WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm

**What are the options to run an animation in WPF when MVVM is used** (and code-behind avoided)?

I have defined my animation in XAML Resources:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="showMe">
     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.5" From="0" To="1" />
</Storyboard>
```

I want to run the above animation on some UI element when a button is clicked. The button has a command binding:

```
<Button Name="btnShowImage" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" />
```

MVVM:

```
Public Property SomeCommand As ICommand
    Get
        If _SomeCommand Is Nothing Then _SomeCommand = New RelayCommand(New Action(AddressOf DoSomething))
        Return _SomeCommand 
    End Get
    Set(value As ICommand)
        _SomeCommand  = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _SomeCommand As ICommand

Private Sub DoSomething
     'no access to View from here so how to run the animation?
End Sub
```

Up to this point I have run the animation from code-behind:

```
Dim stb As Storyboard = TryCast(FindResource("showMe"), Storyboard)
stb.Begin(imgSomeImage)
```

...but that requires I handle the button click event in code-behind which I do not want to do due to MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 2):

How about triggering the animation inside a storyboard within the button clicked event:

```
<Button>
    OK
    <Button.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="showMe">
     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.5" From="0" To="1" />
</Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
      </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
  </Button>
```

Comment: Handling animation from code-behind and at the same time handling business logic from ViewModel? Does it mean that it is needed to define button's click eventhandler AND command binding?